# How to make addin show up in project explorer

Tags: vba, excel

I made my own excel addin, however when I open it "normal.xlam" it does not load in the vba editor. How can I make it show up? I would like to edit it:)

[image]

The addin is added the normal way:
[image]

Comment: You can edit it from a regular workbook if it is installed.

Comment: Looks like your add-in isn't loaded...

Comment: @Mat'sMug  It seems like it only gets loaded as soon as I click a button that is using the addin